# How can I do an image tile in an MDI application?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have tried a lot of code over the year but nothing work 100%
I just need to be able to put an image as the background of my main form, and be able to tile it.

I am using DELPHI 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a component that I wrote years ago, as a part of my freeware component collection, called TrmMDIBackground.  [rmControls v1.92](http://www.mills-enterprise.ca/download/rmctl192.zip) or the [D2009 version](http://www.mills-enterprise.ca/download/beta/rmcontrols2009.zip).

It can display the image as Tiled, Stretched, Centered or display a single solid color.
It would be easy enough to add support for gradient colors, I just haven't done that.

I've provided most of the important pieces of the code here, but looking at the component code in it's entirety would be better as hook window procs looking for specific messages and all of the glue code to make it work.

As to how the drawing goes, I believe that the flicker it not bad (if even visible).  It also only currently supports Bitmap images.

I've added the entire component unit here:

```
{================================================================================
Copyright (C) 1997-2002 Mills Enterprise

Unit     : rmMDIBackground
Purpose  : To allow an image to be placed with in the workspace area of an
           MDI Form.  Background colors are also available.
Date     : 04-24-2000
Author   : Ryan J. Mills
Version  : 1.93
================================================================================}

unit rmMDIBackground;

interface

{$I CompilerDefines.INC}

uses
   Windows, Messages, Classes, Forms, graphics;

type
   TrmBMPDisplayStyle = (dsTiled, dsStretched, dsCentered, dsNone) ;

   TrmMDIBackground = class(TComponent)
   private
      OldWndProc: TFarProc;
      NewWndProc: Pointer;

      OldMDIWndProc: TFarProc;
      NewMDIWndProc: Pointer;

      fBitmap: TBitmap;
      fstyle: TrmBMPDisplayStyle;
      fColor: TColor;

      fBuffer: TBitmap;
      fLastRect: TRect;

      procedure SetBitmap(const Value: tBitmap) ;
      procedure SetDStyle(const Value: TrmBMPDisplayStyle) ;
      procedure SetMDIColor(const Value: TColor) ;

    { Private declarations }
   protected
    { Protected declarations }
      procedure HookWndProc(var AMsg: TMessage) ;
      procedure HookWnd;
      procedure UnHookWnd;

      procedure HookMDIWndProc(var AMsg: TMessage) ;
      procedure HookMDIWin;
      procedure UnhookMDIWin;

      procedure PaintImage;
   public
    { Public declarations }
      constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent) ; override;
      destructor Destroy; override;
   published
    { Published declarations }
      property Bitmap: tBitmap read fBitmap write SetBitmap;
      property DisplayStyle: TrmBMPDisplayStyle read fstyle write SetDStyle default dsNone;
      property Color: TColor read fColor write SetMDIColor default clappWorkspace;
   end;

implementation

uses rmGlobalComponentHook;

{ TrmMDIBackground }

constructor TrmMDIBackground.create(AOwner: TComponent) ;
begin
   inherited;

   NewWndProc := nil;
   OldWndProc := nil;

   OldMDIWndProc := nil;
   NewMDIWndProc := nil;

   fBitmap := tBitmap.create;
   fbuffer := tbitmap.create;

   fColor := clAppWorkSpace;
   fstyle := dsNone;

   fLastRect := rect(0, 0, 0, 0) ;

   HookWnd;
end;

destructor TrmMDIBackground.destroy;
begin
   UnHookWnd;

   fBitmap.free;
   fbuffer.free;

   inherited;
end;

procedure TrmMDIBackground.HookMDIWin;
begin
   if csdesigning in componentstate then exit;
   if not assigned(NewMDIWndProc) then
   begin
      OldMDIWndProc := TFarProc(GetWindowLong(TForm(Owner) .ClientHandle, GWL_WNDPROC) ) ;
      {$ifdef D6_or_higher}
      NewMDIWndProc := Classes.MakeObjectInstance(HookMDIWndProc) ;
      {$else}
      NewMDIWndProc := MakeObjectInstance(HookMDIWndProc) ;
      {$endif}
      SetWindowLong(TForm(Owner) .ClientHandle, GWL_WNDPROC, LongInt(NewMDIWndProc) ) ;
   end;
end;

procedure TrmMDIBackground.HookMDIWndProc(var AMsg: TMessage) ;
begin
   with AMsg do
   begin
      if msg <> WM_ERASEBKGND then
         Result := CallWindowProc(OldMDIWndProc, TForm(Owner) .ClientHandle, Msg, wParam, lParam)
      else
         result := 1;

      if (msg = WM_NCPaint) or (msg = wm_Paint) then
         PaintImage;
   end;
end;

procedure TrmMDIBackground.HookWnd;
begin
   if csdesigning in componentstate then exit;
   if TForm(Owner) .formstyle <> fsMDIForm then exit;
   if not assigned(NewWndProc) then
   begin
      OldWndProc := TFarProc(GetWindowLong(TForm(Owner) .handle, GWL_WNDPROC) ) ;
      {$ifdef D6_or_higher}
      NewWndProc := Classes.MakeObjectInstance(HookWndProc) ;
      {$else}
      NewWndProc := MakeObjectInstance(HookWndProc) ;
      {$endif}
      SetWindowLong(TForm(Owner) .handle, GWL_WNDPROC, LongInt(NewWndProc) ) ;
      PushOldProc(TForm(Owner) , OldWndProc) ;
      HookMDIWin;
   end;
end;

procedure TrmMDIBackground.HookWndProc(var AMsg: TMessage) ;
begin
   case AMsg.msg of
      WM_DESTROY:
         begin
            AMsg.Result := CallWindowProc(OldWndProc, Tform(Owner) .handle, AMsg.Msg, AMsg.wParam, AMsg.lParam) ;
            UnHookWnd;
            exit;
         end;
      wm_EraseBKGND:
         begin
            aMsg.Result := 1;
            exit;
         end;
   end;

   AMsg.Result := CallWindowProc(OldWndProc, Tform(Owner) .handle, AMsg.Msg, AMsg.wParam, AMsg.lParam) ;

   case aMsg.Msg of
      WM_PAINT, // WM_ERASEBKGND,
         WM_NCPaint: PaintImage;
   end;
end;

procedure TrmMDIBackground.PaintImage;
var
   DC: HDC;
   Brush: HBrush;
   cx, cy: integer;
   wRect: TRect;
   x, y: integer;
begin
   if csdesigning in componentstate then exit;
   if TForm(Owner) .FormStyle <> fsMDIForm then exit;

   GetWindowRect(TForm(Owner) .ClientHandle, wRect) ;

   DC := GetDC(TForm(Owner) .clienthandle) ;
   try
      case fstyle of
         dsTiled, dsStretched, dsCentered:
            begin
               case fStyle of
                  dsTiled:
                     begin
                        cx := (wRect.right - wRect.left) ;
                        cy := (wRect.bottom - wRect.top) ;

                        y := 0;
                        while y < cy do
                        begin
                           x := 0;
                           while x < cx do
                           begin
                              bitBlt(DC, x, y, fBitmap.width, fBitmap.height,
                                 fBitmap.canvas.Handle, 0, 0, srccopy) ;

                              inc(x, fBitmap.width) ;
                           end;
                           inc(y, fBitmap.Height) ;
                        end;
                     end;

                  dsStretched:
                     begin
                        cx := (wRect.right - wRect.left) ;
                        cy := (wRect.bottom - wRect.top) ;

                        StretchBlt(DC, 0, 0, cx, cy, fBitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, fBitmap.width, fBitmap.height, srccopy) ;
                     end;

                  dsCentered:
                     begin
                        fBuffer.width := wRect.right - wRect.left;
                        fBuffer.height := wRect.bottom - wRect.top;

                        Brush := CreateSolidBrush(ColorToRGB(fcolor) ) ;
                        try
                           FillRect(fBuffer.canvas.handle, rect(0, 0, fBuffer.width, fBuffer.height) , brush) ;
                        finally
                           DeleteObject(Brush) ;
                        end;

                        cx := (fBuffer.width div 2) - (fBitmap.width div 2) ;
                        cy := (fBuffer.height div 2) - (fbitmap.height div 2) ;

                        bitBlt(fBuffer.Canvas.handle, cx, cy, fBitmap.width, fBitmap.height,
                           fBitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, srccopy) ;

                        bitBlt(DC, 0, 0, fBuffer.width, fBuffer.height,
                           fBuffer.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, srccopy) ;
                     end;
               end;
            end;
         dsNone:
            begin
               Brush := CreateSolidBrush(ColorToRGB(fcolor) ) ;
               try
                  FillRect(DC, TForm(Owner) .ClientRect, brush) ;
               finally
                  DeleteObject(Brush) ;
               end;
            end;
      end;

      fLastRect := wRect;

   finally
      ReleaseDC(TForm(Owner) .clienthandle, DC) ;
   end;
end;

procedure TrmMDIBackground.SetBitmap(const Value: tBitmap) ;
begin
   fBitmap.assign(Value) ;
end;

procedure TrmMDIBackground.SetDStyle(const Value: TrmBMPDisplayStyle) ;
begin
   if fstyle <> Value then
   begin
      fstyle := Value;
      PaintImage;
   end;
end;

procedure TrmMDIBackground.SetMDIColor(const Value: TColor) ;
begin
   if fColor <> Value then
   begin
      fColor := Value;
      PaintImage;
   end;
end;

procedure TrmMDIBackground.UnhookMDIWin;
begin
   if csdesigning in componentstate then exit;
   if assigned(NewMDIWndProc) then
   begin
      SetWindowLong(TForm(Owner) .ClientHandle, GWL_WNDPROC, LongInt(OldMDIWndProc) ) ;
      if assigned(NewMDIWndProc) then
      {$ifdef D6_or_higher}
         Classes.FreeObjectInstance(NewMDIWndProc) ;
      {$else}
         FreeObjectInstance(NewMDIWndProc) ;
      {$endif}
      NewMDIWndProc := nil;
      OldMDIWndProc := nil;
   end;
end;

procedure TrmMDIBackground.UnHookWnd;
begin
   if csdesigning in componentstate then exit;
   if assigned(NewWndProc) then
   begin
      SetWindowLong(TForm(Owner) .handle, GWL_WNDPROC, LongInt(PopOldProc(TForm(Owner) ) ) ) ;
      if assigned(NewWndProc) then
      {$ifdef D6_or_higher}
         Classes.FreeObjectInstance(NewWndProc) ;
      {$else}
         FreeObjectInstance(NewWndProc) ;
      {$endif}
      NewWndProc := nil;
      OldWndProc := nil;
   end;
   UnHookMDIWin;
end;

end.
```

EDIT: Added the image drawing code.

EDIT: Fixed a blinking refresh problem in the first WindProc Handler

EDIT: Added the corrected unit code here

Comment: It seems very good I just can’t get it to work
Can you provide a small sample on how to use the “TrmMDIBackground” class? Thanks

Comment: Sorry.  That would be my fault.  The package is missing a file.  There is supposed to be a compilerdefines.inc and that is not in the package.  In making the demo I found and fixed a refreshing problem with the component.  I'll post what I can here and send you the rest of the files in an email.

Comment: Can you send me an email @ rmills (at) mills-enterprise [dot] ca?  I'll send you a demo project.  I'm not sure why you can't get it to work.  Unless the compilerdefines.inc file you have doesn't recognize d2007. you might have to update it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it's going to work, but I found [Change MDI parent background](http://www.greatis.com/delphicb/tips/lib/forms-mdibackground.html).

> The decision consists in interception
>   of the `WM_ERASEBKGND`, `WM_VSCROLL` and
>   `WM_HSCROLL` messages and carry out draw
>   of area by using `DrawImage` procedure
>   or `InvalidateRect` procedure. `CreateWnd`
>   procedure uses `SetWindowLong` procedure
>   for installation of new procedure of a
>   window. Don't forget to remove line
>   `Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2)`
>   from project file and line `var Form2: TForm`2 from unit2.pas file.

```
// This procedure tiles the image on the form's client area 
procedure TForm1.DrawImage;
var
  i, j: Integer;
  WndRect, ImageRect: TRect;
  Rows, Cols: Integer;
begin
  GetWindowRect(ClientHandle, WndRect);
  ImageRect:=Image1.ClientRect;
  Rows:=WndRect.Bottom div ImageRect.Bottom;
  Cols:=WndRect.Right div ImageRect.Right;
  with Image1 do
    for i:=0 to Rows+1 do
      for j:=0 to Cols+1  do
        BitBlt(MyDC, j*Picture.Width, i*Picture.Height, Picture.Width,
          Picture.Height, Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
end;
```

Comment: This one as some problems.
It flick quite a lot, and if you drag it into a secondary screen the background is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, in the MDI forms OnPaint procedure add the following

```
Canvas.Lock;
try
    Canvas.Brush.Bitmap :=  MyImg.Picture.Bitmap;
    Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,ClientWidth,ClientHeight));
finally
     Canvas.Unlock;
end;
```

But it still flickers when you manually re-size the form, due to the excessive repaints. There are windows messages saying that a form is been resized that you could hook into, and not update until the form has finished resizing.

These windows messages would do the trick :

- [WM_EXITSIZEMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632623%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632622%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [WM_SIZING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632647%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

By *background* I am assuming you mean the *client region* of the main *MDI frame* window.

This area of the screen is handled by the *MDI Client window* so one way to do this would be to subclass the *MDI Client* window and then process the *WM_PAINT* message.